# Alone Amidst the Stars - Finding the original star system after warping to 10+ star systems?

Tags: no-mans-sky

How do I figure out how to find the original star system (or even if that is necessary) to continue one of the main quests, `Alone Amidst the Stars`?

The game says my next objective is `Triangulate your position: place second space beacon`.

Comment: Quests can be reset, all explored stars can be seen in Journal/Map and if you find something exceptional - mark it with the base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Press `Escape` to make sure the quest is selected.
- While in flying in space, press `m` for the star map.
- The star system will have a red and white icon on it.

I don't know how this would work for someone who has gone considerably more than my 37 light years however.

As a reminder press `z` and use the `signal booster` to get the `triangulate position` option.

Comment: Would also add that a quest can be reset is the destination is too far away. i had the Cadmium quest reset because the selected Red Star was too far away and the First Traveller mission where you search a crashed freighter can lead to an already visited one making the mission impossible to complete, i've read that if you go into a Black Hole you can end up far enough away to give you the option to reset